# Is there a "best way" to send Google feedback?

Tags: google, google-photos, google-feedback

I did use the feedback thing, but I have no idea if that is the best way. I'll be honest, I don't think they will ever read it, but I wanna try all my options.

If this helps, my feedback is about a missing feature: photos.google.com already uses tags, I can change/add tags in picasa and upload them, then when I search it finds pics based on tags. However the process is very backwards, un-intuitive and broken. If only they would add a small, bare bones feature where all you can do is add/delete tags without having to go trough the sync/block uplad & re-upload head-ache mess.

Comment: Did you try this link: http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/

Comment: @serenesat I should have been more precise, that is exactly what I used. But the product forum is a more, face-to-face thing. I also posted there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below link shows how to send feedback for Google's product:

[Help improve Google’s products](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/) .

If you want to send the feedback to the Google photos team click on below link:

[Welcome to the Photos Help Center](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156065?hl=en&ref_topic=6156079&vid=0-635760032728677491-1426014233).

Or you can join [Google Photos Help Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/115899483237483386886) to start a discussion. You will get expert comments here.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, especially for that last link! To add to this: The google product forum doesn't exactly list photos, but silly me, I didn't type it in the search. It is there, it's just not listed. Probably not popular enough.

Comment: I notice the google feedback thing doesn't work with safari. I'm getting annoying messages advertising chrome when I use google's search engine _on safari_. Which I can't report.

Answer (score 1):

Google is getting increasingly difficult to give feedback to.

The location varies by product.

**Google Sheets** Under help, "Help Sheets Improve"

**Google Docs** Under help, "Help Docs Improve"

**Calendar** Circle question mark top right, "Send Feedback to Google"

**Gmail**  Circle question mark top right, "Send feedback to Google"

**Google Search** Very bottom of page, "Send Feedback"

**Google Maps** Bottom right in 4 point squint type, "Send Feedback"  Unless it's a map error choose the bottom item on the menu.  None of the others allow for a comment.

Most feedback allows you to include a screen shot.  This will NOT include a dialog box, or some other kinds of popup boxes.  E.g. the info balloon on a map pin nor will it work from all screens.  E.g. Sending google feedback about the gmail settings page is difficult.

Google will not acknowledge this at all, except for certain map errors.

I also collect these in files.  I have  "Wishlist for Sheets" that is now 29 pages long, "Wishlist for Gmail" which is now 4 pages long.  When I find a likely audience I paste chunks into it.

---

As far as I know, no one from Google reads their own product forums, and they certainly don't read stackexchange, even though they suggest SE for finding solutions.  They do not read reddit's google groups.