# Choosing the folder for documents uploaded through Google Calendar?

Tags: google-drive, google-calendar

If I upload an image to Google calendar event it appears in the root of my Gdrive.

Is there any way I can specify the folder for calendar uploads?

I found this topic on Google forum with no answer though https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/b-2K6tj4G6g

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't at this time. You could use Google Feedback to send a feature request.

Related

- [Is there a "best way" to send Google feedback?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82708/88163)